# Google Analytics Uses Asterix in URL

Tags: php, google-analytics

In google's new Measurement Protocol they have the ability to send custom dimensions through to google analytics.

I've setup the custom dimensions as per Google's Instructions and I've been given two indexes:

- OrderIDA = Index 1
- OrderIDB = Index 2

I have these setup to record on a hit-by-hit basis and I'm using PHP to send the data to google.

In their specifications they [have this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#customs):
`cd[1-9][0-9]*`
and the example for it is: `cd[1-9][0-9]*=Sports` the value obviously being `Sports`.

What perplexes me is that I am given a single index starting at 1 which accounts for the first parameter and not the second. Even further is their use of the asterix which I understand is a reserved character but what it's purpose is in this case I have no clue.

Because I am using PHP I am trying to setup the query strings by passing an object to `http_build_query` which I'm sure won't produce and asterix unless it's part of a string so this confuses me even more.

What I have tried is to send `cd[1]=value` and `cd[1][0]=value` which don't appear to be coming through. I'm yet to try `cd[1][0]*=value` but that makes me think I am barking up the wrong tree.

So the question is, how am I meant to be passing custom dimensions through to Google Analytics correctly using their Google Measurement Protocol? And if I need to use an asterix, is there a way of achieving this using the above methods or will I have to append to the query string manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, my things are that the asteriks is an placeholder. But i've found not really informations about that. `cd[1-9][0-9]*` is **invalid**, that is that why you can't reproduce it. The best solution is to contact the Google Support (direct contact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, think of those specifications as regex strings. You'll have the string "cd" plus a digit plus possibly another digit (think ? instead of *).

Per your example, you'll have 2 URL parameters as such:

```
cd1=OrderIDA&cd2=OrderIDB
```

If you were to use dimension 15, you'd end up with:

```
cd15=Foobar
```

Same goes with metrics (#1 = 1 and #15 = 1,625)

```
cm1=1&cm15=1625
```

Comment: Excellent response thanks. I've tested this and it worked straight away. I'm going to see if I can get google to update their documentation to make this as clear as possible.